# Storage Spaces unusable read speed

Tags: hard-drive, powershell, storage-spaces

I've created a Storage Space with parity using 10 2TB disks and transferred 10TB onto it. However I am getting appalling read speeds.

When I try and copy data off it, it takes ages to get going (filling the buffer) then bursts to over 100MB/s (empty's the buffer) then the read speed falls to pretty much zero and I can't get anything off it.

I'm assuming the only way to smooth out the read is with some power shell commands like the Set-StoragePool -FriendlyName Backup -IsPowerProtected $true I used to fix the write speed (I wish I had never found this, I would have ditched Storage Spaces there and then) but I can't find the relevant commands or settings.

Please help because this is looking like total data loss at the moment.

Comment: Using `IsPowerProtected` without a cache backup battery isn’t a good idea. Also, it only really affects writes. How are those disks of your connected to the PC? What’s the CPU doing when it’s slow?

Comment: I have a UPS connected. The drives are connected via SATA and the CPU isn't doing anything.

Comment: And how is that SATA controller connected to your system? Are all of the disks connected to the same controller? Well, while we’re at it, just provide a complete overview of the system’s hardware, to help identify potential bottlenecks. And so you’re saying the CPU is (still) idling when it’s slow, right? Did you actually verify this?

Comment: What size files are you trying to move off?

Comment: The system is as follows,
Intel Core i5 2500K, 8GB RAM, 8 on board SATA ports I believe this is accross two controllers and a four port add in card making a total of 10 ports plus an eleventh for the OS on an SSD.

I was trying to copy a MKV which was over 4GB, I have also tried with smaller files which was a none starter.